# Firestore - Nested query

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm really new to firebase and to be honest I find queries hard to write. I'm working on a script in python using `firebase_admin` and i'd like the query/answer to be in python code, but in any other programming language is fine.

Here's my one of my document, one document contains `photos` set

```
photos: {
    id1: true
    id2: true
}
```

I want to be ale to retrieve all items where they have ***id1*** in photos object, what would be the query for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the [Firebase documentation on simple queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) shows:

```py
# Create a reference to the photos collection
ref = db.collection('documents')

# Create a query against the collection
query_ref = ref.where(u'photos.id1', u'==', True)
```

For the `.` notation, see the documentation on [fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Note that you'll probably want to change your data model to use an array for this data, as [arrays can now be used to model mathematical sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership). With a an array like this in your document:

```
user: ['id1', 'id2']
```

You can then filter with:

```
photos_ref = db.collection('documents')

query = photos_ref.where(u'photos', u'array_contains', u'id1')
```

To add/remove items to this array-that-behaves-like-a-set, see the documentation on [updating elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

Comment: What does the `u` signify? Not sure I've ever seen this

Comment: It means it's a unicode string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279331/what-does-the-u-symbol-mean-in-front-of-string-values

Answer (score 1):

Based on Frank van Puffelen's solution, I was also able to use the dot notation to achieve the nested effect. Querying for objects where the assignment contains the current user's ID.

```
objectModel: {
      objectName: 'foo',
      otherField: 'bar',
      assignment: {
          installerIds: ['1', '2', '3'],
          otherfields: 'foobar'
      },
}
```

I was able to query like this

p = { field: 'assignment.installerIds', operator: 'array-contains', value: this.currentInstallerId}
query = query.where(p.field, p.operator, p.value);

or in a more general format like Frank showed:

```
query_ref = ref.where('assignment.installerIds', 'array-contains', '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the where clause is changed now, won't take 3 parameters as mentioned above.

If anyone looking for the same answer, check below
This is in Flutter, but the syntax is similar

```
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('documents')
    .where('photos. id1', isEqualTo: true)
    .get();

    final document = snapShot.docs.first.data();
```