# Firestore - query where filter of object in array field

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have question about query in firecloud.

For example, see my document:

[image: document]

i need filter all documents where the account_id is "value" and "approve" is true. How i do it?

I tried: where("members.account_id", "==, "qgZ564nfEaNP3Nt4cW1K3jCeVlY2") and not work:

See, this is a question that not for specific language, just about firestore query, after undestand, i go apply it in my code.

I'm programing in flutter.

Comment: Which firebase dependency are you using? `cloud_firestore` or `firebase` on pub.dev?

Comment: I think you can't querying key value type array contains in cloud firebase you have to filter that data on client side.
```
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

```

Comment: According to this answer, you cannot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600915/firestore-how-to-query-data-from-a-map-of-an-array

Comment: I have this exact structure and i thought it would be easy, but its seems there is no way to perform this query in firestore. What would be the best way to achieve this in the client side? thanks for any suggestion

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637467/2126077

Answer (score 33):

If you query like this:

```
where("members.account_id", "==", "qgZ564nfEaNP3Nt4cW1K3jCeVlY2")
```

Firebase checks if there's a nested field `/members/account_id` with the given value. And such a field doesn't exist, because the value is actually at `/members/0/account_id`.

Since you don't know the position in the array the the ID exists, you instead want to use an `array-contains` condition. With `array-contains` Firestore checks if the array you contains the exact member that you specify.

With your current structure you can check if the member exists with:

```
.where("members", "array-contains", { accountId: "qgZ564nfEaNP3Nt4cW1K3jCeVlY2", approved: true })
```

So you must know the entire data of the array element in order to use `array-contains`.

If you only know a single member, while you're storing multiple members, you can't use `array-contains`. In that case, I recommend adding an additional `member_accountIds` field to each document, where you store just their account IDs:

```
member_accountIds: ["qgZ564nfEaNP3Nt4cW1K3jCeVlY2", ... ]
```

With that in place, you can query like this:

```
.where("members_accountIds", "array-contains", "qgZ564nfEaNP3Nt4cW1K3jCeVlY2")
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a double quote (") on the first code block.

Comment: Thanks for flagging. Feel free to fix it next time you spot something like that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you, i undestand, i need create node of array with all acocuntIds. thank you.