# Query DB to get a value from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

My database is like this:

[image]

I'm trying to the for example "Ricardo Meireles" with the following code:

```
const getTarefasFuncionario = async () => {
    setTarefasFuncionario([]);

    const q = query(
      collection(db, "tarefas"),
      where("funcionarios", "array-contains", {
        photoURL: currentUser.photoURL,
        value: currentUser.displayName,
      })
    );

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    const tarefas = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      tarefas.push({ ...doc.data() });
      console.log(doc.data());
    });

    tarefas.forEach((tarefa) => {
      const data = tarefa.dia.toDate();
      const options = { day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit", year: "numeric" };
      tarefa.dia = data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR", options);
    });

    setTarefasFuncionario(tarefas);
  };
```

But its not getting anything, I tried to use the firebase query system like this:

[image]

But it also did not work, what am I doing wrong?

I'm expecting a an array of "tarefas" that contains the user as a "funcionario"

Answer (score 1):

The `array-contains` operation looks for an item in an array that is an exact, complete match to the value you specify. So to match the items in your array, you need to specify both the value **and** the photo URL. There is no operator to do a partial match on array items.

The common workaround is to add an *additional* array field with *just* the value you want to search on, e.g.

```
funcionarioNames: ["Ricardo Meireles", "cristano"]
```

With that additional field, you can now perform an `array-contains` on `funcionarioNames`.

Also see:

- [Firestore - query where filter of object in array field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374452/firestore-query-where-filter-of-object-in-array-field/59376295#59376295)
- [Firestore array-contains-any is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052349/firestore-array-contains-any-is-not-working-properly/59053018#59053018)
- [Firestore: How to query data from a map of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600915/firestore-how-to-query-data-from-a-map-of-an-array/54601567#54601567)

Comment: I see what you did, I'm trying this "work around" `const q = query(
      collection(db, "tarefas"),
      where("funcionarios", "array-contains", {
        photoURL: currentUser.photoURL,
        label: currentUser.displayName,
      })
    );`

like what I saw in other link that you send me, but it doesnt work either.

I'm not sure if I can use what u send because, some "tarefas" can only have one person, in that case (the print) it had like 3 users, but some other cases it would be only 1

Comment: I edit the code from the question with the current one

Comment: Don't change your question in this way *after* somebody posted an answer already please, as that makes it useless to future visitors. Please revert to show the original code, and then potentially show the updated code as an edit (although that should really be a new post).