# Firestore retrieve docs with where clause object in object

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the jobs that Grade value New/Near New inside the job.
`job->container->grade` Equal to New/Near New.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked? [Firestore - Nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857592/firestore-nested-query)

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo i am using react JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all jobs with a grade value of New/Near New, you can [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) like this:

```
// Create a reference to the jobs collection
var collectionRef = db.collection("jobs");

// Create a query against the collection.
var query = collectionRef.where("container.grade", "==", "New/Near New");
```

And then you [execute the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) as also shown in the docs.

Comment: You saved me @Frank . I also want to know about how to set multiple filters inside the where clause programmatically or dynamically. I am using react js i want to set multiple where clauses depend on user input. eg: 1st case User want to filter Status and Created time same time, 2nd case User want to filter status, Created time, Grade same time. How to set Filters depend on user selection>