# firestore finding nested object that contain some properties accross different collections

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857966/10964992 works only for a collection( because it only works for a given collection )

how to get a list of doc across differentt collecion (let say, contain a name attribute and type attribute  equal to some value)?

**let say we have 2 document in post collection. Each has an apply collection, which have a number of doc (applicants).  I want to find that doc that have a specific applicationID.**

```
collection doc   collection doc        properties  
Jobposts  ID1    apply     APPLICANT1  {"applicationID":XXXXXX}
                           APPLICANT2  {"applicationID":XXXXXX}
          ID2    apply     APPLICANT5  {"applicationID":XXXXXX}
                           APPLICANT7  {"applicationID":XXXXXX}
```

I dont care about performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search across all `apply` collections, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). This will read/query across all collections named `apply`.

Be sure to study the documentation first, as there are some requirements across your security rules and indexes to make this possible.