# Firestore: query where clause > nested field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter and Firestore. Suppose my database looks like this:

```
[
  {
    Name: 'John',
    Address: {
      Street: "John doe street"
      Postal: "12047"
    }
  },
  {
    Name: 'Mary',
    Address: {
      Street: "Fleet street"
      Postal: "1242B"
    }
  }
]
```

I now would like to search for all persons whose postal code contains '12'. So that would mean both records in this dummy database.

But how can I filter on the nested field 'Address.Postal'?

```
var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var query = '12';
ref.collection('users')
        .where(
          'Address.Postal', // Won't work
          ... // There is no 'like' operator or something that looks alike
        );
```

FYI the project being in Flutter is irrelevant.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637467/2126077

Answer (score 4):

The [`where()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/Query/where.html) function now accepts a [`FieldPath`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/FieldPath-class.html) instance as the first argument. This allows you to reference either nested fields or the [`documentId()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/FieldPath/documentId.html) in your query.

Example:

```dart
queryText = '12';

postalRef = new FieldPath('Address', 'Postal');
ref.collection('users')
        // Equivalent of LIKE "queryText%"
        .where(postalRef, '>=', queryText)
        .where(postalRef, '<=', queryText+ '\uf8ff');
```

As for the Firestore equivalent of SQL LIKE statements, [this answer explains it better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56815787/13692641). However, the short explanation is that you can use the `>=` and `<=` operators to query your `string` field by character values.

`\uf8ff` (Private-Use Area  ) is just a commonly used delimiter for this operation since:

- it's a very high unicode character
- it's outside what you'd expect in a web-based "text search".

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check for a specific property in the array items. All you can do is check whether the entire item is present with [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership). But for that you need to know the entire array item, so all name and address properties.

If you only have the name, there is no built-in operator to test whether any array item contains that name. Instead you'll want to extract just the names into their own array (say `addressNames`) and then use `array-contains` on that.