# Firestore - get the parent document of a subcollection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Screenshot of my database as requested]I'm working on an app that uses a firestore database with the following hierarchy:
parent_collection:
                  parent_document:
                                  subcollection:
                                                child_document{
                                                     string name}
using collectionGroup I've been able to query subcollection for documents with a certain name, but I don't know how to get the parent_document

```
 db.collectionGroup("subcollection").whereEqualTo("name", searchText).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                          //here I want to get the parent id of all results
                        }
                    }
                });
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: it'll be helpful if you attach screenshot of database

Comment: How do you get to subcollection if you don't know parent since path to subcollection is `/collection/{parent_id}/subcollection`?

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it and please indicate the exact data that you want to get. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I add a screenshot as requested, I just wanted the question to be more general.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `QuerySnapshot` points to a number of `QueryDocumentSnapshot` instances.

From a `QueryDocumentSnapshot`, you can get the collection it's from with:

```
snapshot.getRef().getParent()
```

And then the parent `DocumentReference` is:

```
snapshot.getRef().getParent().getParent()
```

So to get a subscollection of the parent document with:

```
snapshot.getRef().getParent().getParent().collection("name_of_subcollection")
```

Yes, I agree... that could've been a bit more readable. :)

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I believed there must be a simple solution for it and here it's.

Comment: I usually am pretty good at getting things from the reference docs, but this time I had to ask around. All the `getBla` was getting in my way. :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky =D. I couldn't find it on my own too.

Comment: does this only work for android development? It seems not to work with javascript.. Is there a way to get this in javascript?

Comment: It should work very similarly in JavaScript. Something like `snapshot.ref.parent.parent.collection("name_of_subcollection")`. It's mostly a matter of following the trail in the reference docs, starting with [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot). If you're having a hard time making it work, you might want to post  new question showing what you tried (see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and linking back to this question/comment for reference.

Comment: FWIW, this syntax worked for me (Nodejs v14.3+): `snapshot.ref.parent.parent`

Answer (score 1):

In case you use stream:

```
docs = db.collection_group(u'collection_name').stream()
for doc in docs:    
        path = doc.reference.path # will get you the full path
        # then you can manage the path as string
        sub_path = path.split('/')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = value.getDocuments();
                for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documentSnapshotList) {
                    DocumentReference dr = documentSnapshot.getReference().getParent().getParent();
                    // or any field documentSnapshot.get(field);
                    assert dr != null;

                  ));
                } //for end
```

Comment: Already answered by Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score -1):

You can get documents of a collection like this:

```
if(task.isSuccessful()) {
        List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = task.getResult().getDocuments();
        for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : documents) {
            documentSnapshot.getId();
            // or any field documentSnapshot.get(field);
        }
}
```

Comment: this will get the documents of the subcollection, not the parent document, it looks like you misunderstood my question.

Comment: so you want to get collection based on this `documentSnapshot`?