# Query parent collection using sub collection in Firestore with angular8

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular8

I have a parent collection (class) and sub collection (students)  of that parent collection. 'student' collection has a field called student_id. What I need is to get all the classes for particular student_id.

I have spent much time on searching for an answer but could't find an answer. Please help me.

I have tried this one. but not working

```
export class ClassService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  loadClasses(studentId: String) {
    return this.db.collection('class', ref => ref.where('students.student_id', '==', studentId)).get();
  }
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it.

Comment: This looks a lot like [Firestore - get the parent document of a subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219469/firestore-get-the-parent-document-of-a-subcollection) Can you try and let me know whether it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't support querying of the parent collections' documents by supplying a condition to match its sub-collection's documents yet.

However there's a workaround you can use. You can use [collections-group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) to find all the student documents that match the `studentId` in all the students sub-collections and query the parent document of each student document.

I would suggest an alternative database structure where `Student` and `Class` are seperate collections for your use case.

Hope this helps.