# Firestore - set a POJO field to the ID of the collection of a query

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I know this is a very specific ask but I've got a situation where it would be very nice to have my custom class deserialized and have the collections parent ID set to a specific field. I know with the `@DocumentId` annotation we can do this for the documents own ID, is there some SDK method to extend this for my use case?

```java
public class MyCustomClass {
    @DocumentId public documentID;
    ...

    @<insert magic here> public documentsCollectionsParentID
```

So for example, something like `/users/<uid>/docs/<docid>`, I already have the functionality for documentID to be set automatically to `docID`, but I'd like `documentsCollectionsParentID` set to `uid`. Is this in any way possible at the moment?
My current alternative is to deserialize, and the the object afterword:

```java
MyCustomClass thing = (MyCustomClass)doc.toObject(MyCustomClass.class);
thing.setDocumentsCollectionsParentID(doc.getReference().getParent().getParent().getId())
```

Comment: I came across similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219469/firestore-get-the-parent-document-of-a-subcollection), let me know if it's helpful in your case.

Comment: @mdobrucki Unfortunately, not much help as I already am able to do this manually, but seek a method to do this automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no method in Firebase that does that automatically. This is Java limitation and you are doing it correctly by deserializing the object.

Comment: "This is Java limitation" I'm not convinced it a limitation of Java itself, I could maybe see the SDK. After all if it can set a document ID field to be a certain property of the response, there's nothing fundamentally different between that and my use case.