# How to query documents containing an array of objects in Firestore with python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection, users,  that contained a field which is array of object:
 `{"status":"active", "children": [{"name": "jack", "id": 1234}]}`

I'm trying to search on this collection and find the user that children.id equals to 1234.

I tried with this:

`db.collection('users').where('children', 'array_contains', {'id': 1234}).get()`

and also this:

`db.collection('users').where('children.id', '==', 1234).get()`
but did not work.

How can I do these kinds of queries on firestore?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't query this way and this question was already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600915/firestore-how-to-query-data-from-a-map-of-an-array). You need to revise your data structures.