# Python firestore query for nested fields

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am filtering documents from Firestore in Python from the collection named "students". I am using a Pydantic model for **Student** that includes a ListField for **locations** with the **Location** model and in that location model i am having the **id** field. Despite having the document in my database for the location id = 1234456, when executing the query below, I am getting an empty list ([]):

```
query = db.collection("students").where("locations.id", "==", "1234456").get()
```

Below is my single **document** structure

```
{
    name: "tom"
    roll_no: "13024578"
    age: 24
    locations: [
    {
       "id": "1234456",
       "place": "England"
    },
    {
       "id": "432432",
       "place": "Canada"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your document structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Updated @AlexMamo

Comment: check this thread if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54600915/firestore-how-to-query-data-from-a-map-of-an-array

Comment: Please edit your question and add your document structure as a **screenshot**.

Answer (score 1):

This condition in your query:

```
.where("locations.id", "==", "1234456")
```

Matches a JSON structure that looks (exactly) like this:

```
"locations": {
  "id": "1234456"
}
```

And since you don't have that JSON structure in your document, it doesn't match the query.

---

What you seem to be trying to do is to perform a partial match of an item in an array. That's not possible with Firestore though. Operators such as `==` and `in` look for complete matches, not for partial matches.

To allow the use-case, add an additional array field to the document with just the location IDs:

```
locationIDs: [ "1234456", "432432" ]
```

Now you can query that field to find the documents with the location ID you want:

```
query = db.collection("students").where("locationIDs", "array-contains", "1234456").get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is assuming `locations` is a map, whereas your document's data shows it is a table. Hence you get nothing back.

What are you trying to do? Get all students which have a given location's id among all their locations?
For this you will have to change your document structure:

1. Create a sub-collection `locations` under `student` with each document being a location {id, place}
2. Make a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) on `locations` specifyng the id. You will get a list of `locations` document back
3. You can deduce the students'id from the previous result, you can then retrieve each student's data as needed